# Can Tesla valve concept work for electrons?

Tags: semiconductors

This is a Tesla valve. It works by diverting liquid or gas back on itself when it is flown in one direction and allowing a smooth flow in the other direction.

[image: tesla valve]

Can the same concept be used to create a semiconductor? Why?

Comment: It would perhaps be more reasonable to think of a Tesla valve as a poor facsimile of a diode than to attempt to think of how to make a semiconductor function like a Tesla valve.  A Tesla valve is quite leaky and it's main advantage is the lack of moving parts and perhaps fast response.  A diode also has no moving parts and within reason and within your budget, it can be arbitrarily not leaky, arbitrarily fast, etc.  To justify making a semiconductor that used the same principles as a Tesla valve, you would have to find some parallel for it's operating principle that would have some advantage.

Comment: That said, perhaps there is some way.  I think diodes perform more like a one way mechanical one way valve than a Tesla valve, so maybe you can invent a diode with near instantaneous(compared to the current fastest diodes) response.  Probably not, but it's fun to think about.

Comment: I 'suspect' that you (just maybe) may be able to achieve something like this effect using thermionic emission and charged structures. Nothing as "fine" as the 'Tesla valve' probably, but something that bends electron streams in curved paths in one direction and accelerates them in the other. I (idly) wonder if there is anything in a Magnetron design that may be bent (pun noted) to this function.

Comment: It's not a Tesla valve, but there has been some recent work on geometric diodes which are targeting THz rectennas. For example https://www.mdpi.com/2079-4991/11/9/2361/pdf

Answer (score 11):

No. The design of the Tesla valve requires a material which has inertia (so that the "slanted" paths are preferred for backflow), and which behaves as a viscous fluid (so that the pressure of the reversed backflows can obstruct forward flow). Neither of these is applicable to the movement of electrons within a conductor.

Comment: I'd agree on the absence of viscosity for electrons, though their inertia is real enough. Surface tension and molecular attraction (not the apparently similar Coanda effect) are required for the fluid to stick to the inclined walls, also absent from electrons.

Comment: Well, if you take the *top level* concept of the Tesla Valve as "a magical thing that lets flow go in one direction but not the other" then you have a diode, either semiconductor or thermionic.  I doubt that's what the OP meant, however.

Comment: Diods unfortunately cause voltage drop which does not happen in tesla valve. With a pancake solenoid made of wire funcioning as a tesla valve, one could rotate bar a magnet over the surface of the pancake and pump current out of it, right?

Comment: @doker, the equivalent of the voltage drop is the pressure drop on any fluid fluid restriction.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should work if you use a 2-dimensional-electron gas (2DEG) or maybe just a thin film semiconductor e.g. SOI. You could structure it quite simply with established technologies and then to test it arrange it as a bridge rectifier and source AC and check if you get out DC. The only parameters you really need to think about is what size to make it, what AC frequency to use and at what temperature. I am quite certain, that it doesn't work if you use copper wires at macroscopic scale and room temperature, but with semiconductors you can tune the mass of your charge carriers and the mean free path, so it does more behave like the fluids where we know that this structure works. I would try it with a mean free path which is a bit smaller than structural features and go up with the frequency as far as your equipment allows e.g.: most labs should be able to do 1MHz.

Probably a very nice idea for a bachelor or master thesis, but practically it will probably be much less efficient compared to conventional diodes when it comes to blocking currents, but possibly it could be more efficient at special applications e.g. rectification of very low voltages, which reminds me of a proposal I recently read for a perpetuum mobile which converts Brownian motion into small voltage signals via bi-stable membranes...

P.S.: Found a work about semiconductors where electors behave like a liquid: https://phys.org/news/2022-07-explore-hydrodynamic-semiconductor-electrons.html

Answer (score -1):

If you had a motor which you oscillated between acceleration and electronic braking, about once per second, and if you didn't want to drive the motor straight off of the batteries, e.g. because they are LiPo and you don't want to drain and recharge them like this, wouldn't it be nice if you could drive the motor with a capacitor, and connect the capacitor to the batteries with an electric Tesla valve, so that the voltage in the capacitor doesn't drain back into the batteries.

Comment: It sounds like you are describing a diode.