# Tesla valve/ valvular conduit

Tags: rf, transformer, electromagnetism, microwave, power-amplifier

What happens if a radio or any electromagnetic wave passes through Tesla valve/valvular conduit? How will the valve behave to an EM wave? What will be the output?
Will the EM wave behave exactly as fluids?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Tesla valve concept work for electrons?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/430198/can-tesla-valve-concept-work-for-electrons)

Comment: @user1937198 In my opinion the question adresses a different approach to an electronic analogon of the tesla valve. The linked question and the answers don't deal with EM waves in any way. So this is a new question in my eyes.

Comment: So is there any idea, how to simulate the Tesla Valve for an EM wave as input?